# MEAN stack and concurrency

Tags: concurrency, mean-stack

What is the preferred way of handling concurrent users for a web app powered by the MEAN stack? What I really mean is that in a multi-user environment, users can update the same object, for example a collection with students and the users update grades, how would we handle it? My initial thought is that there is a need for an optimistic lock with a versioning hookup, so for each update we want to cross-check the versionid. Does frameworks like mongoose handle it?

Answer (score 0):

This should be dealt with at the Mongoose level, as you suggest. This may answer your question: http://aaronheckmann.tumblr.com/post/48943525537/mongoose-v3-part-1-versioning 
Note particularly that *Mongoose v3 now adds a schema-configurable version key to each document*